# How to display properties of Child Scope in view - created using $scope.$new() syntax?

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am pretty new to AngularJS.

I have created a child scope in my controller as shown below. but the model is not available / binding is not happening in the html view.

i'm not sure how to specify the model name in HTML View

```
var App= angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('myController', function ($scope,$rootScope, $http) {
    var model = $scope.$new();
    model.id = "1";
    model.modelName = "New Model";
    model.cityCode= 1212;
    model.country= "USA";
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div  ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
         <label>{{modelName}}<label/>
         <input type="text" ng-model="modelName" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're binding the wrong object.
In a controller you already have the `$scope`. it references the variables that you can use in the view. You don't need to create a child scope inside.

instead of `..neW(); model.id=..` use `$scope.id=...;`

rule of thumb: there should be a dot in `ngModel=mymodel.field`. this isn't the cause of your problem, but it'll save you trouble. otherwise the prototype chain won't work as most people think it will. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=29m19s

I set it live here http://jsfiddle.net/5qu54/

IF you insist on using the new scope, you have to recompile the element of the controller. the `$compile` service binds an html element to the scope you tell it. See it live here http://jsfiddle.net/5qu54/1/

```
app.controller('myController', function ($element, $scope,$rootScope, $compile) {
    var model = $scope.$new();
    model.id = "1";
    $scope.modelName = "New Model";
    model.cityCode= 1212;
    model.country= "USA";

    console.log("my element is", $element.html()); 
    $compile($element.contents())(model);
});
```

And in the html I added the country to see the binding `<label>{{modelName}} {{ country }}<label/>`
try commenting/uncommenting the `$compile(...` line

update:
about `$rootScope` and `$scope`:
scopes can be: shared, prototypically inherited (which can be new from rootScope) or isolated. sometimes you have to create one. for example, you created a directive that repeats elements because you didn't like the default ng-repeat. each element needs an isolated scope. or you have a model in $rootScope.myModel and you need a new "clean" scope with access to everything you have already in $rootScope: $rootScope.new();.
You should read this http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope carefully.
in your case, though, you needn't create another scope. in the controller you bind decide what to expose to the UI, as you'd normally do with a MVC architecture. creating scopes is normally used in the `link` function of directives.

about `$compile`: sometimes you add elements to the dom that "can be" directives. for example, there is a directive myDir in directives.js, you dynamically add `<my-dir>aloha</my-dir>` to the DOM (e.g. the link function of another directive appends html somewhere). Now you have an element that *can* trigger a directive but angular still doesn't know that it is there. you compile the element, angular now knows about it and runs the code.

Comment: Hi Eduard, thanks for the quick response. I'm confused ! in which scenario we should use the $scope.$new() or $rootScope.$new() ??

it would be a great help if you could guide me on this. angularjs documentation describes about child scope. but not clear on the usage.. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope